# Convert str to int in Python from CSV file column

Tags: python, python-3.x, mapreduce

I am struggling in converting a string type to integer in Python. What I am trying to do is read a specific column from a CSV file and pass it as an integer. Here is my code:

```
import sys

   for line in sys.stdin:
       line = line.strip()
       line = line.split(",")
       tMax = line [9]
       tMax2 = int(tMax)

       if len(tMax) <=4:
           print (tMax2)
```

When I run this, I get the following error,

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10
```

I checked the type of the column and it is accepted as a string.

Comment: There may be some other non-numeric character in the string. It still is a string, but there is maybe a space, dot, or other which makes it impossible to use `int()`

Comment: @Signal - without an explanation of why ```It's typically better .. ``` it just sounds like your opinion.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to me that, since it's complaining about the `int()` conversion, there's a problem with whatever you have in `tMax` before attempting said conversion.

That can easily be discovered by adding the line:

```
print('[' + tMax + ']')
```

immediately before the attempted conversion.

This should actually show you the problem reasonably clearly, at which point you can go on to figure out *why* the string value is not what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

I skipped the most important part of the error - the actual description. The error `invalid literal for int() with base 10` had `:TMAX` which means it was complaining about the header. I removed the header and it ran beautifully. I know there is a better way in reading in a file without removing headers; I will learn that soon.